# Warning message 1: and 2: use rgdal::readOGR or sf::st_read

Tags: r

I am a Archaeological Masters student currently completing my dissertation on the spatial awareness of the historical use of Roman forts.

Please bear with me as I am not a coding person and need help in understanding how to run my programmes please.

I am using RGui run admin and come across an error when loading my shape file to the coding.
I enter my shape file as:

```
x<-readShapeSpatial("QGIS Castles.shp")
```

A warning returns as:

> `Warning messages: 1: use rgdal::readOGR or sf::st_read  2: use rgdal::readOGR or sf::st_read`

Can anyone help please?  If I continue with my programme of directions the data in the end does not show as a graph.  Thank you.  Laura

Comment: Please provide more of your code if you want someone to help you.

Comment: It seems that maptools (or parts of it) is on its way to deprication. Therefore, your function `readShapeSpatial` will work for now, but if you need to implement it in scripts also needed in the future you might switch to the two functions listed.

Answer (score 0):

From the [official changelog](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/maptools/ChangeLog) and the [github repo commit](https://github.com/cran/maptools/commit/7ad17152311212e11759b52a5ddb15214eb64fbc#diff-3a10d5273ad9e6994aac548278e440d3) we can see, that the function is deprecated.

```
2017-02-23 08:23  rsbivand

    * R/Spatial-methods.R, R/SpatialLines-methods.R,
      R/SpatialPoints-methods.R, R/SpatialPolys-methods.R,
      man/readShapeLines.Rd, man/readShapePoints.Rd,
      man/readShapePoly.Rd, man/readShapeSpatial.Rd: set .Deprecated
      for maptools shapelib use
```

Therefore, your function `readShapeSpatial` will work for now, but if you need to implement it in scripts also needed in the future you might switch to the two functions listed.

Hence, the more reliable code would be

```
library(rgdal)
x <- readOGR(dsn = ".", layer = "QGIS Castles") # DO NOT ADD ".shp" to your shapefile name
```

or

```
library(sf)
x <- st_read("QGIS Castles.shp")
```

Comment: So I've downloaded the package "rgdal" and installed it successfully, but can't find any packages with the names "readOGR" or "sf::st_read".  Am i missing something?  Apologises for the possible stupid questions, please remember I do not know code.  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Loki, really appreciated.  Can I ask a further questions please?  The "rgdal" package allows me to change my data to spatialpoints, but then won't let me change it to "ppp" for using in Ripley K analysis.  I get the message: Error in .class1(object) : argument "object" is missing, with no default.  I can't use "sf" package as that uses dataframe, which is not what I am needing.

Comment: I think that is another issue. I have no experience with ppp. A quick web search revealed [this extensive article](http://spatstat.org/resources/spatstatJSSpaper.pdf). I think you should work with rgdal for that issue and extract the `spatialPointsDF@coords`. Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for your help Loki, really appreciated.

Comment: If this specific question was answered, you might consider marking the checkmark by the answer.